# Error while using set command remotely while using batch file in PSTools

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, dns, centos7

I want to add DNS remotely to a system and for that I am using PsExec tool and batch file as:

```
echo "Please enter new DNS Information" 
set /p add_dns=Enter your DNS 
netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers "LAN" %add_dns%
pause
```

This works fine on the same system, but not for remote system: when I enter DNS 192.168.0.1 it is not taking the whole DNS. It shows this error:

```
**D:\test>set /p add_dns=Enter your DNS
Enter your DNS 192.0.0.1
D:\test>netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers "LAN" 1
The parameter is incorrect.
'2.0.0.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
D:\test>pause**
```

Any suggestion how to change DNS remotely by prompting for DNS address rather than entering manually in .bat file?

Comment: Can you put `%add_dns%` in the netsh command between doublequotes? It seems that the 9 somehow breaks up the command causing your batch file to execute `netsh interface ipv4 add dnsservers "LAN" 1` and after that on a new line `2.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks Dennis, but its still showing same error. My batch file works fine on my system but showing error while running remotely on other system.

Comment: I tested some other things like opening and using notepad and found that PSExec open them but can't edit them in running time situation on remote system. Similarly, maybe it not allowing me to enter IP on real time.  Any more suggestions please?

Comment: have you tried echoing `%add_dns%` to see what the variable contains? does it contain the IP like you would expect?